# Angular 2 add/remove/select all - item from array

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want to make a simple selection of items - where people could select from my `Array(a)` and add to `Array(b)`. Also they can remove from `Array(b)` and they can select all `Array(a)` to `Array(b)` - then deselect the unwanted. Simply :

> 1.Array(a).item.clicked --> Array(b).item added
>
> 2.Array(a).item.clicked 2nd time --> Array(b).item.deleted
>
> 3.Array(a).selectAll = Array(b) { if(selected.all) { Array(a).item.clicked --> Array(b).item.removed   } }

My start (example with explanation) :

```
oneFunctionForAll(){
    if(clicked-first-tiem) {
      addCompare(item)
      }
    }
    if(clicked-second-time){
  removeCompore(item, i)
    }

    if(selected-all-and-clicked) {
      removeCompore(item, i)
    }

if(selected-all-and-clicked 2nd-time) {
  addCompare(item)
}

  }
  addCompare(item) {
    this.compare.push(item)
    console.log('Prideda',this.compare)
  }

  removeCompore(item, i) {
    const index = this.compare.indexOf(i)
    if (index !== -1) {
      this.compare.splice(index, 1);
    }
    console.log('triname',this.compare)

  }
```

HTML :

```
    <ion-card *ngFor="let item of jsonObj | slice:0:4; let i = index" 
class="relative" (click)="oneFunctionForAll(item,i);"> </ion-card>
```

If you have some ideas or done it before, I would like to see how you implemented this. I am struggling now for some reason. Please write if need more information - I will provide it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a very simple version: [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4np9ps)

I'm using `Set` to "toggle" items, and I have a separate function to select all items from the original array.

```
sourceArray = [
  'Alice',
  'Bob',
  'Charlie',
];

selected = new Set();

toggleItem(item: string) {
  if (this.selected.has(item)) {
    this.selected.delete(item);
  } else {
    this.selected.add(item);
  }
}

selectAllItems() {
  this.selected = new Set(this.sourceArray);
}
```

You could, if needed, also rewrite the `toggleItem` function to use an array as the target instead. Probably by finding trying to find the item index, and then either `splice`ing the selected items on that index, or adding the item instead, if it's not there yet.

Answer (score 1):

If I were you, I would use a set of observables to handle that. Angular is shipped with RxJs anyway, so you might aswell take advantage of it.

Here is an example on stackblitz :

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tpuigb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css

Simply click on the items to mve them from a column to another.

As you can see, the code is very simple and short, and doesn't require much to work.

```html
<h1>Click on an item to select it</h1>

<div class="container">
  <div class="values">
    <div class="value" *ngFor="let item of available$ | async" (click)="select(item)">{{ item.value }}</div>
  </div>
  <div class="selected">
    <div class="value" *ngFor="let item of selected$ | async" (click)="unselect(item)">{{ item.value }}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  values = [
    { value: 'Lorem', selected: false, },
    { value: 'Ipsum', selected: false, },
    { value: 'Dolor', selected: false, },
    { value: 'Sit', selected: false, },
    { value: 'Amet', selected: false, },
  ]

  values$ = new BehaviorSubject(this.values);

  available$ = this.values$.pipe(
    map(items => items.filter(item => !item.selected))
  );
  selected$ = this.values$.pipe(
    map(items => items.filter(item => item.selected))
  );

  select(item) {
    item.selected = true;
    this.values$.next(this.values);
  }

  unselect(item) {
    item.selected = false;
    this.values$.next(this.values);
  }
}
```